# Vue Cli 3 Npm Run Build Error: Callback was already called

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3, npm-run

Everything works fine until this error shows out. I can run npm run serve with no problem except npm run build.

Here's the error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~prebuild: mop_client2@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~build: mop_client2@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\mop\mataonlineportalclient\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\xampp\php;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Predator Onii\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Predator Onii\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Predator Onii\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Predator Onii\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\mop\mataonlineportalclient
10 silly lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mop_client2@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: mop_client2@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid mop_client2@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\mop\mataonlineportalclient
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mop_client2@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mop_client2@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here's what I did so far:

1. npm cache clean -f
2. npm install
3. check out to another branch to see if I did something wrong with my code.
   None of these fixes solved the problem.

I don't know what causes the problem it's been 4 days already. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer and tried module.exports = { css: { extract: false } } to vue.config.js hope it helps everyone.